# Pygame resizable window, surface not updating appropriately

Tags: pygame

I am using pygame to draw graphs with some different graph drawing algorithms. Previously I had the size be constant but now I want it to be re-sizable. I was able to get the resizing to work in certain cases. For example, it works when I press the resize window button at the top of the client and properly fills the surface in. However, if I try to resize the window by dragging the corners out I have to do it very slowly otherwise it wont work. Is there a way to have pygame update faster with me dragging. I've looked at other examples but was unable to make it work in my case, maybe cause I'm using thorpy too?
The main-loop event code is:

```
playing_game=True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while playing_game:
    pygame.event.pump()
    event=pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        playing_game = False
        pygame.display.quit()
        break
    elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        myMenu.display = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE) 
        myMenu.resize(200, event.dict['h'], event.dict['w'], event.dict['h'])
        myMenu.itemMenu.blit_and_update() 

    pygame.display.update()  
    clock.tick(60)
    myMenu.itemMenu.react(event)
```

The entire code can be found at: https://github.com/CamiloJac/GraphVis

***Working properly when resize window button is pressed***
[image: BarycentreSpringFullscreen]

***Working incorrectly when I drag the edges of the screen***
[image: IncorrectResizing]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the combination of `pygame.event.pump()` and `event=pygame.event.wait()` is causing the event to be lost.

The `event.wait()` is only processing a *single* event, then the `pump()` tells PyGame to handle the remaining events.  I'm guessing some kind of syncopation is happening, and the resize is being lost.

I have this sort of re-sizing working with processing all events:

```
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

...

while ( not done ):

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            window        = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
```

Comment: I tried doing it with the event loop earlier and I was running into the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: This is specific to Ubuntu because I tried it on a windows machine and the resizing worked correctly.

Comment: @Camilo - I believe you, but that works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 & 19.10.

Comment: Hmm, okay I'll try messing around with it. That's good to know though that it works for you on Ubuntu.